# Problems with loading gnuplot scripts on OS X (10.9.5)

Tags: macos, gnuplot

I have problems with command 'load'. 
For example my script is something like this:

```
set xlabel ‘blabla’
```

But when i try to load this, I get:

```
load '/Users/.../gnuplot.txt'
                 ^
     "/Users/.../gnuplot.txt", line 1: invalid character ?
```

I figured out that adding "reset" before the whole script change the error message:

```
set xlabel ‘blabla’
                 ^
     "/Users/.../gnuplot.txt", line 2: invalid character ?
```

But when I write everithing into the terminal by myself, I get no errors...

Any idea how to fix it??

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You are using the wrong quotation marks (Left and Right single quotation marks, codepoints [U+2018](http://www.decodeunicode.org/de/u+2018) and [U+2019](http://www.decodeunicode.org/de/u+2019)).

You must use ASCII single or double quotation marks, either `'` (0x27) or `"` (0x22).

Comment: Yes, this was the problem! I used Plain Text Editor instead of TextEdit and suddenly everything works fine!  Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

Try putting this line before your `load` command

```
set encoding utf8
```

The `invalid character` smacks of using the wrong character set.

Comment: I tried what you've suggested but unfortunately, results are still same... But thanks for your effort :)

Comment: It looks like you have invalid characters in your file `gnuplot.txt`. Try running `cat -vet gnuplot.txt` and looking for anything weird. Click `edit` under your question and paste the output of the command above.